# Is it possible to cycle through MarkerFaceColor in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

As an example, I want to do precisely the following:

```
cc=gray(100);

for i=1:100
    plot(i,i,'o','MarkerFaceColor',cc(i,:,:));
    hold on;
end;
```

...but without the for-loop, i.e. automatically iterated -- something like:

```
i=1:100;
plot(i,i,'o','MarkerFaceColor',cc(i,:,:));
```

Clearly the following works:

```
i=1:100;
plot(i,i,'o');
```

...but I want matlab to automatically iterate over the color space for each newly plotted point. In practice, I have a far more complicated example that uses embedded for-loops but this takes far to long to plot. N.B. I'm really no matlab expert.

Anyhow, I was hoping that this is possible and if so, what the correct syntax might be.

Thanks for reading and any insight you might have,

Cheers,

Ben.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [scatter](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/scatter.html) function. It takes an additional color vector which you can build yourself from a colormap. Adding the 'filled' option as the last parameter will make filled markers.

So I think something like the following should work:

```
cm = gray(100);
x = 1:100;
scatter(x,x,[],cm,'filled')
```

Comment: Thanks robince, I think this might do the job..(just verifying :-) )